# Avoid "rm" in makefile

Tags: linux, make, deployment

I have a question concerning a line in a Makefile. I have a target to "clean" my locally installed test/staging-server. Currently it looks like this:

```
clean:
    rm -rf $(LOCAL_SERVER_PATH)/*
```

As long as the variable `LOCAL_SERVER_PATH` is defined and looks like `/srv/www/htdocs` or something like this, everything is fine. But ... what if a user made a mistake and mistyped the variable-definition, or some config-step went rouge, and the Makefile is created, with a wrong definition.

Essentially, I fear, that by mistake I could end up with a non-defined `$(LOCAL_SERVER_PATH)`, and my target would then yield to:

```
clean:
    rm -rf /*
```

Is it possible to refactor my Makefile to make it more robust against such errors? I don't want to end up with a Makefile, that could potentially wipe out my entire linux-installation (or even parts of it, since my user is not 'root').

Comment: You could just check the variable beforehand, you know? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, check the variable to ensure that it is not empty:

```
clean:
    test -n "$(LOCAL_SERVER_PATH)" && rm -rf $(LOCAL_SERVER_PATH)/*
```

The same idiom appears in a large number of RPM spec-files, where it seems that the `BUILD_ROOT` variable has been known to be unset.  Since its replacement is not universally available (despite the comments a while back in *[Re: [Fedora-packaging] Phase out buildroot?](https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-packaging/2009-May/msg00111.html)*), it can still be found here and there.

Comment: You may want to also check for '..' and ';' in the variable also if your paranoid, else a variable of '../../../../../../../' makes a sad panda.

Comment: If you were truly paranoid, you would not cleanup in a makefile.  I was reading one of those last night, for a code review.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `test` command, you can test for the variable in the Makefile and behave differently – e.g. show an error to the user, therefore refusing to run the Makefile:

```
ifeq (,$(LOCAL_SERVER_PATH))
$(error Set LOCAL_SERVER_PATH variable to run this Makefile)
endif
```